# About commuting mapping in d3.js... any advice?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have to make some representation of the commuting daily movement in the north Italy.
I have a database of 4500 municipalities and the data about sources, destinations and number of commuters for each of the 4500 municipalities...

At this initial stage my main issue is to decide which kind of representation could be the more useful and readable. Than I'll menage the issue of make it in d3 :-)

I've made a quick survey online to see how other people managed the representation of big dataset and I fount this example made in d3:

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/bundle.html

[image]

and this one not in d3:

http://peoplemov.in

[image]

Have you any other suggestion about this kind of representation? any other example?
My main concern is the readability of the representation with 4500 point of origin/destination. from this point of view maybe the second example is the best one.

Comment: With this many points, even the second one would be hard to read. I would suggest having something like a [chord diagram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006) for an aggregated version of the data set (e.g. by region) and when you click on a region show more detailed data for that. You definitely need some kind of hierarchical approach that doesn't show you all the data to start with.

Comment: This is also my idea. But the main problem is that I'm interested more on the trans-regional or trans-provincial commuting rater than on the hinterland -> main city.
I'll need some sort of filter to show only the trans regional ora trans provincial movement.
Maybe a full representation could be base on a map with zooming capabilities.

Comment: This would be the idea for the top-level chord diagram. It would show the flows between provinces/regions. You can of course show that as a bipartite graph as in the second example as well.

Comment: You are right, but in this way the cross-province movement are represented only in an aggregate way. This could be a first step but it will be important to understand which are the municipality that attract people from other province and from which municipality they come. Maybe I have to make a chord diagram and a representation like the 2 I linked before using only the data of cross-province movement. Than I could make a map of all the movement using different color for the different province of destination: something like this one http://xliberation.com/googlecharts/d3flights.html

Comment: In any case, you're not going to get a definitive answer here.

Comment: Definitive answer no... but you helped me in clearing my mind. As soon as I'll get the dataset I'm sure I'll post some more specific question about chord diagram :-) Thanks for the support!